# How can I extract the 64base value & replace the value in json format using awk or sed?

Tags: json, awk, sed

How can I extract the base64 value shown below? I was trying to use something like `awk {'print $14'}`, but this doesn't work because the entire output is first item. If I decode the base64 value first, then I'm able to use `awk {'print $14'}` to eventually obtain the value that I need.

> $ curl -s --request GET http://10.0.10.10:8500/v1/kv/w-key-value

```
[{"LockIndex":0,"Key":"w-key-value","Flags":0,"Value":"WyAgeyAgICBDcmVhdGVJbmRleDogMTAwLCAgICBNb2RpZnlJbmRleDogMjAwLCAgICBMb2NrSW5kZXg6IDIwMCwgICAgS2V5OiB6aXAsICAgIEZsYWdzOiAwLCAgICBWYWx1ZTogMSAgICBTZXNzaW9uOiBhZGY0MjM4YS04ODJiLTlkZGMtNGE5ZC01YjY3NThlNDE1OWUgIH1d","CreateIndex":4080,"ModifyIndex":4080}]
```

Comment: With GNU grep: `grep -Po '"Value":"\K[^"]*' file` or with GNU sed: `sed 's/,/\n/g' file | sed -nE 's/^"Value":"(.*)"/\1/p'`

Comment: Great! that works. thanks.